# “replace” a 3-tuple

Tags: haskell

I have the following list (it’s a length 2 list, but in my assignment I have a length +n list)

```
xxs = [(11,22,[(33,33,33),(44,44,44)]),(55,66,[(77,77,77),(88,88,88)])]
```

I’m trying to “replace” one 3-tuple (p1 or p2 or p3 or p4 from the image bellow) by list index (`n`) and by sub-list index (`p`).

[image: Visual of list breakdown]

The function, at the end, should be like:

```
fooo newtuple n p = (…)
```

For example: (replace p3 for (98,98,98):

```
fooo (98,98,98) 2 1 
[(11, 22, [(33,33,33) , (44,44,44)]) , (55, 66, [(98,98,98),(88,88,88)])]
```

I planned the code like following this steps:

1. Access the pn that I want to change. I manage to achieve it by:

   ```
   fob n p = ((aux2 xxs)!!n)!!p
      where aux2 [] = []
            aux2 ((_,_,c):xs) = c:aux2 xs
   ```
2. “replace” the 3-tuple. I really need some help here. I’m stuck. the best code (in my head it makes some sense) that I’ve done: (remember: please don’t be too bad on my code, I’ve only been studying Haskell only for 5 weeks)

   ```
   foo n p newtuple = fooAux newtuple fob 
        where fooAux _ [] = [] 
              fooAux m ((_):ds) = m:ds
              fob n p = ((aux2 xxs)!!n)!!p
                 where aux2 [] = []
                       aux2 ((_,_,c):xs) = c:aux2 xs
   ```
3. Finally I will put all back together, using `splitAt`.

Is my approach to the problem correct? I really would appreciate some help on step 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a bit new to Haskell too, but lets see if we can't come up with a decent way of doing this.

So, fundamentally what we're trying to do is modify something in a list. Using functional programming I'd like to keep it a bit general, so lets make a function `update`.

```
update :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
update n f xs = pre ++ (f val) : post
  where (pre, val:post) = splitAt n xs
```

That will now take an index, a function and a list and replace the `nth` element in the list with the result of the function being applied to it.

In our bigger problem, however, we need to update in a nested context. Luckily our `update` function takes a function as an argument, so we can call `update` within that one, too!

```
type Triple a = (a,a,a)
type Item = (Int, Int, [Triple Int])

fooo :: Triple Int -> Int -> Int -> [Item] -> [Item]
fooo new n p = update (n-1) upFn
   where upFn (x,y,ps) = (x,y, update (p-1) objFn ps)
         objFn _ = new
```

All `fooo` has to do is call update twice (once within the other call) and do a little "housekeeping" work (putting the result in the tuple correctly). The `(n-1)` and `(p-1)` were because you seem to be indexing starting at `1`, whereas Haskell starts at `0`.

Lets just see if that works with our test case:

```
*Main> fooo (98,98,98) 2 1 [(11,22,[(33,33,33),(44,44,44)]),(55,66,[(77,77,77),(88,88,88)])]
[(11,22,[(33,33,33),(44,44,44)]),(55,66,[(98,98,98),(88,88,88)])]
```

Comment: First of all, your explanation was real remarkable. Second: I still have much to learn, but I learned a lot with your answer. Third: I spend half of my day trying to solve this, and you solve it in a few minutes (I really have lot to learn and study). Finally, a BIG thanks! _o_

Answer (score 4):

So you've tried using some ready-made function, `(!!)`. It could access an item in a list for you, but forgot its place there, so couldn't update. You've got a solution offered, using another ready-made function `split`, that tears a list into two pieces, and `(++)` which glues them back into one.

But to get a real feel for it, what I suspect your assignment was aiming at in the first place *(it's easy to forget a function name, and it's equally easy to write yourself a new one instead)*, you could try to write the first one, `(!!)`, yourself. Then you'd see it's real easy to modify it so it's able to update the list too.

To write your function, best think of it as an equivalence equation:

```
myAt 1 (x:xs) = x
myAt n (x:xs) | n > 1 = ...
```

when `n` is zero, we just take away the head element. What do we do when it's not? We try to get nearer towards the zero. You can fill in the blanks.

So here we returned the element found. What if we wanted to replace it? Replace it with what? - this calls another parameter into existence,

```
myRepl 1 (x:xs) y = (y:xs)
myRepl n (x:xs) y | n > 1 = x : myRepl ...
```

Now you can complete the rest, I think.

Lastly, Haskell is a lazy language. That means it only calls into existence the elements of a list that are needed, eventually. What if you replace the 7-th element, but only first 3 are later asked for? The code using `split` will actually demand the 7 elements, so it can return the first 3 when later asked for them.

Now in your case you want to replace in a nested fashion, and the value to replace the old one with *is dependent on the old value*: `newVal = let (a,b,ls)=oldVal in (a,b,myRepl p ls newtuple)`. So indeed you need to re-write using functions instead of values (so that where `y` was used before, `const y` would go):

```
myUpd 1 (x:xs) f = (f x:xs)
myUpd n ... = ...
```

and your whole call becomes `myUpd n xxs (\(a,b,c)->(a,b,myUpd ... (const ...) ))`.

Comment: It's a solution closest to that one I've tried. I'll try to complete the (...). The explanation is all there. :)   Thank you!!

Comment: @Nomics what I meant was, to write your function, think of it as if you've written it already, as if you had it available for your use already, and just write down some equivalence equations based on the qualities it's supposed to have, laws it's supposed to follow. These equations will become the definition of the function themselves - as long as you follow the laws of it, keep the invariants before and after its use, e.g.: _the list with 1st elt replaced is just that; the list with _n_th elt replaced is the 1st elt prefixed to the rest of it with _(n-1)_-th elt replaced._ That's it.

Answer (score 4):

First, we need a general function to map a certain element of a list, e.g.:

```
mapN :: (a -> a) -> Int -> [a] -> [a] 
mapN f index list = zipWith replace list [1..] where
  replace x i | i == index = f x 
              | otherwise = x
```

We can use this function twice, for the outer list and the inner lists. There is a little complication as the inner list is part of a tuple, so we need another helper function:

```
mapTuple3 :: (c -> c) -> (a,b,c) -> (a,b,c)
mapTuple3 f (x,y,z) = (x,y,f z)
```

Now we have everything we need to apply the replace function to our use case:

```
fooo :: Int -> Int -> (Int,Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int,[(Int,Int,Int)])]
fooo n p newTuple = mapN (mapTuple3 (mapN (const newTuple) p)) n xxs
```

Of course in the inner list, we don't need to consider the old value, so we can use  `const :: a -> (b -> a)` to ignore that argument.